# On interior of topological subspace

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space with a subspace $(Y, \tau_Y)$.
Let then $A$ be a subset of *Y*. There is the fact, that $Cl_YA = Cl_XA \cap Y$. The same is not correct for the interior of A. Trivially, when $A = Y$ and $Y$ contains its boundary, then the whole $Y$ is open in the sense of a space, but closed as the subspace of $X$, so the intersection of $Int_XA$ with $Y$ will cut off the boundary. But I'm interested, is there any other example, when $Int_YA ≠ Int_XA \cap Y$?

Answer (score 1):

Take any $Y$ which is not open in $X$ and take $A=Y$. Then $Int_Y A=Y$ which is not open in $X$ so it cannot be interior in $X$ of any set.