# About interior of a set in a subspace

Tags: general-topology

**Question:**
Let $Y$ be a subspace of a topological space $X$ and let $A\subseteq Y$. Denote the $\operatorname{Int}_X(A)$ as the interior of $A$ in the topological space $X$ and $\operatorname{Int}_Y(A)$ as that in the topological space $Y$. Show that $\operatorname{Int}_X(A)\subseteq \operatorname{Int}_Y(A)$. Give an example where the relationship cannot be an equality.

**Answer:** The answer is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/447879/145325). As for the example where the relationship cannot be an equality, that is addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4155461/145325).

**My Question:**
The fact that $\operatorname{Int}_X(A)\subseteq \operatorname{Int}_Y(A)$ is really bothering me because I cannot really build an intuition around it. The interior of a set w.r.t the *larger* space $X$, is a subset of the interior of the same set w.r.t the *smaller* space $Y$, where I am using *larger*/*smaller* in the sense that $Y \subseteq X$. Why is that? Isn't it natural to expect the opposite? Why is it turning out to be the way it is? I completely understand the proof but somehow, I cannot build an intuition around it. Please help me understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a point $x$ to be in the interior of $A\subset X$ (with respect to $X$) means that all the point of $X$ close enough to $x$ are also in $A$ (ie $A$ contains a neighborhood of $x$).

Now, for $x$ to be in $\operatorname{Int}_Y(A)$, you need all the points of $Y$, close enough of $x$, to be in $A$. Since $Y\subset X$, there are less points that we need to consider, so this is a weaker condition.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess you have more points to "worry about" in the set $X$ than in the set $Y$. Now I can recollect that there is a notion of a *weaker topology*. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be an interior point of $A$ wrt. $X$, i. e.

there is a set $O$ open in $X$, s. t.

$a \in O \subset A \subset X.$

Since $A \subset Y \subset X$,

$a \in O\cap Y \subset A$,

where $O\cap Y$ is open in $Y.$

Recall: $G$ is open in $Y$ iff $G=U \cap Y$ for some open  set $U$ of $X$